# What happens with the code after the recursion line ?

Tags: java, recursion

I want to ask exactly what happens with the code after the recursion line ?

Here is sample code :

```
public static void method(int index){
    --index;
    if (index < 0) {
       return;
    }


    method( index);
    System.out.println(index);

}
```

My question is why sout prints my number in reverse order  when it is after the recursion line : 0 1 2 3 4

Thanks in advance.

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: Well, despite the name of the other question, the concept of stepping over recursive methods is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before each print you call method(number-1)

When reach -1 you start calling the recursion stack from 0 until your number `index`

The stack is piling and we keep popping the last one from stack:

```
0
1
...
number-1
number
```

Answer (score 0):

Your application is single thread, so all instructions are executed one after one.

Once you call a method next line is called after method completes.

Your execution of `method(4)` is as it follows:

```
method(4)
method(3)
method(2)
method(1)
method(0)
method(-1)
```

- here, there is no more recursion call - method returns before calling `method` another time. Look, it returns, so we fall back to `method(0)` execution - `print 0` is executed. Then we return and finish `method(1)`:

```
print 0
print 1
print 2
print 3
print 4
```